# Making fried pickles ahead of time

Tags: freezing

I want to deep fry some pickles, but I want to have them ready ahead of time.  The coating I like is a sort of cornmeal buttermilk batter. How can I freeze these without it all coming off?

Comment: Do you want to freeze after frying, or batter then freeze then fry?

Comment: Is it even possible to freeze without a partial fry?

Comment: I have no idea, honestly, but thought it might be a detail worth including :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mean freeze after frying. The bad news is that there is probably no foolproof way of retaining the crispness of fresh-fried pickles through freezing. A few tips to prevent them from being limp/soggy:

1. After frying, please make sure each of them are cooled out in open air (like in a cooling rack on baking sheet etc) instead of a locked container and/or stacked on top of each other. This prevents them from being all soggy from the slow-releasing steam.
2. You need to thaw them/slightly bake them in a oven to bring back some of the crispiness. Microwave thawing will turn them mushy.

Comment: Reheating by baking on a preheated baking stone will result in maximum crispiness.  Not sure if they'll be as crispy as straight from the fryer, but I think that will get them as crispy as possible for a reheated item.